# Why I can't accept the right answer?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example, I can't click the right answer of [this page](http://answers.ros.org/question/41456/where-is-pcd_viewer-on-ros-fuerte/?answer=41495#post-id-41495).

I also met this kind of problem at other ros answer page.

How to fix it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41708/why-i-can%27t-accept-the-right-answer?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try clicking it and then reloading the page.  Sometimes the checkbox doesn't refresh after clicking it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1